# Multi language settings and getting string array item - android

Tags: android, arrays, string, settings, preferences

I want to make my app settings with multi language support. Value of settings item will be different in each language. I have string array:

```
<string-array name="syncTemperature">
        <item>@string/celcius</item>
        <item>@string/fehrenheit</item>
</string-array>
```

Which is used in:

```
<ListPreference
                android:key="prefTempUnit"
                android:entries="@array/syncTemperature"
                android:summary="@string/pref_temp_current"
                android:entryValues="@array/syncTemperature"
                android:title="@string/pref_temperature" />
```

and when I will call:

```
String celcius = sharedPrefs.getString("prefTempUnit", "Celcius")
```

I will get different value everytime.
My question is how to have one value for all strings under one item.
For example when I want to check what user choose and make some action after.

Like this:

```
if(prefTemUnit==celcius){
    setTempUnitToCelc();
}
```

**EDIT:**

For now I figured out one option:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String unit=sharedPrefs.getString("prefTempUnit", "Celcius");
    String[] stringArray =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.syncTemperature);

    if(unit.equals(stringArray[0])){
        //mymethod
    }
```

but I dont know if its the proper one.

Comment: I don't understand. What value?

Comment: @ARMAGEDDON In short I want to have possibility to make last "if" statement. 

If I will call sharedPrefs.getString I get string under string array item, dependently on user language. I want to have one if statement for all languages.

Comment: why are you using SharedPreferences in your case?

Comment: @ARMAGEDDON in MainActivity in onCreate method. I want to check user preferences on app start and display weather with selected unit. But that's not relevant. I tried to set name for array item but I get "attribute name is not allowed here"

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got your solution:

First of all: 
`String celcius = sharedPrefs.getString("prefTempUnit", "Celcius")` will return "Celcius" as a default value. Maybe you should remove it?

Second:
If you would like to access the String value according to the actual language, you should use:

```
String retrievedValueFromStringXML = getResources().getString(R.string.celcius);
```

To add:
`ListPreference` has a method called `getValue()`, you should use it as well to retrieve the actual value.

Comment: I have added my solution to first post.